# get first occurrence of a space after last occurrence of parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex, sublimetext3

I'm trying to dice up a dictionary text file (using Sublime text editor) and need to get the first occurrence of a space after the last `)` because I need to replace it with a delimiter I can import into Google sheets.

E.g., The following:

```
abierto (masculine) open

abjaso (masculine); abjasio (masculine) Abkhaz

abogado (masculine); abogada (feminine); notario (masculine)    lawyer
```

Should be (note the `_` delimiter):

```
abierto (masculine)_    open

abjaso (masculine); abjasio (masculine)_    Abkhaz

abogado (masculine); abogada (feminine); notario (masculine)_   lawyer
```

How can I accomplish this?

---

**EDIT**: I've tried `/\)[^\)]+$/g` - to get a `)` followed by one or more non-) characters, at the end of the string, greedy... but it only finds one result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\)(?!.*\))
```

to find last occurrences of `)`, then replace that with `)_`, which gives you the desired result. Here is a result from ST3

[image]

Explanation:

```
\)   # find ")"
(    # OPEN capturing group 1
  ?!    # negative lookahead, aka "do not match"
  .*    # anything until
  \)    # character ")"
)    # CLOSE capturing group 1
```

So if you have eg regex `a(?!b)`and test it on "ab", "ac" and "ad", it will match only the "a" if it precedes something that "*does not match*" b. So the "a" in "ac" and "ad" is being matched here. But not in "ab". Here, the `)` is selected on everything until `)`

From comment:

> Can you help explain this? Also, can you explain why this doesn't work in Regex101? regex101.com/r/GFwrn5/1

That is because you have not enabled the global `/g` flag there. If you enable it, it will do the job.

Comment: Can you help explain this? Also, can you explain why this doesn't work in Regex101? https://regex101.com/r/GFwrn5/1

Comment: @Growler updated with explanation. IF you want to know more, you can check for negative lookahead [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use greedy match `.*\)` to get last `)` using this regex to match:

```
/(.*\)) /
```

and then replace it by:

```
$1_\t
```

Where `\t` is for tab (you can se 4 spaces instead of `\t` as well.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/B62X6g/1)